# Difficulty in plotting current location(longitude and latitude) of user on google maps

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I wrote a code using this tutorial http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/311.html It is working fine except the plotting part.It is showing longitude and latitude but not showing them on google map.Can anyone tell me error in this code which is not allowing to plot the coordinates on map. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/QbvfQzvG

Comment: You mean you want a marker or something? The current code will only hover to the point

Comment: No the code is not showing address and thus not showing that address on google map.

Comment: What is the lat, lon shown? Also, is this shown in the log : LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data"

Comment: The lat and lon are the test coordinates which I'm giving using geo fix.They are shown perectly but their corresponding address is not shown.

Comment: Maybe that location has no address? Did you see : ""Could not get Geocoder data" ? can you try with some other location?

Comment: I tried it on different lon and lat as well but it is not showing address and that point on map.Logcat is showing 10-26 16:20:41.069: E/LocateMe(299):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) (yes it is showing Could not get Geocoder data )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use MapController.setCenter() instead of animateTo()

```
pointToShow= new GeoPoint(iLat,iLong);
MapController control=mapView.getController();
control.setCenter(pointToShow);
```

That works fine for me...

Comment: Do you have active internet connection? what is shown on your map - can you see map itself, or it is just blank space?

Comment: I fixed that address problem by running application on  API 7  but not map is not showing up.Can you help me with this? yes I have very good internet connectivity.

Comment: hmmm... are you launching your app on phone or in emulator&

Comment: I'm launching my application in  emulator (Google api 7).

Comment: and do you have permission for internet in your manifest? i have just tested mapView in emulator and all is fine.

Comment: also, i'd better check is this error reproducing on real device - emulator is VERY buggy. Another thing - i'm using sdk r13 - haven't upgrade it to r14.

Comment: Yes I have internet permission,I have not tested the application on real device and I'm using r14 but the thing is it was working fine when I posted this question.After taking Reno's advice I switched to google api 7 (earlier google api 8) and it stopped working but showing address.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try 
    {
     List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); //<10>
     for (Address address : addresses) {
          this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0));
    }

   .... 

  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("LocateMe", "Could not get Geocoder data", e);
  }
```

Since an Exception is thrown,  "Could not get Geocoder data" was called,

- This could be due to lack of the INTERNET permission
- Bug in the Emulator 2.2 API 8 : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

  java.io.IOException: Service not Available
   at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:117)
- `addresses` might be `null` so a NPE is thrown

Comment: There is bug in API 8 but when I ran it on API 7 the address is shown but google map is not showing up.There is only Google written over a white background,Why is it so?

Comment: It is best if you work with real devices, the emulator has some problems like these.